# SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, token

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.view-kettha-links div.view-content').hoverscroll
    ({
        width: 225,
        height: 100,
        vertical: true,
        arrows: true,
        arrowsOpacity: 0.7; --> chrome detect as SyntaxError: Unexpected token
    });
});
```

chrome detect as SyntaxError: Unexpected token but still working,in firefox the function is fine but in IE the function didn't works at all,needs help please.

Comment: When you remove the semicolon, be sure **not** to replace it with a comma.

Answer (score 11):

```
arrowsOpacity: 0.7;
// remove this....^
```

Assuming it is in your source code and wasn't added by Chrome as part of its error message, remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the semicolon on that line.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because an JavaScript object is separated by commas (,) not semicolons (;). JavaScript objects must not contains semicolons, using semicolons in objects throws an error. So that's why, there is no need for the last semicolon from the line `arrowsOpacity: 0.7;`, just remove the semicolon and your code will start working